# Why is my matrix not unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, unitary-matrices

I've to find a matrix unitary matrix U, so that $U^* A U= diag(A)$. Or in other words: I've to find a unitary Matrix U that diagonalizes A.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}i&1&i&-1\\-1&i&1&i\\i&-1&i&1\\1&i&-1&i\end{bmatrix} $

I've calculated the Eigenvalues ($\lambda_1 = -2i \wedge \lambda_{2,3,4} =2i$) and the Eigenvectors...

$V_{\lambda_1} = \begin{bmatrix}-i\\-1\\i\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $V_{\lambda_2} = \begin{bmatrix}-i\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $V_{\lambda_3} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $V_{\lambda_4} = \begin{bmatrix}i\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

After Normalization the Matrix U should be...

$U=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-i}{2}&\frac{-i}{\sqrt2}&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&\frac{i}{\sqrt2}\\\frac{-1}{2}&
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&0&0\\\frac{i}{2}&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&0\\\frac{1}{2}&0&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$

But that's not true, because $U^*U \neq I$

Any suggestions what went wrong?

Comment: It seems to me like you only normalized the eigenvectors. Did you apply Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: Why do you think the eigenvectors should be orthogonal, with this particular $A$ matrix ?

Comment: Oops, i forgot about that